# What are the advantages of using forEach vs for?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, foreach

I'm currently writing a web app that needs to print out a list of values from an array.

At the moment I am getting the length of the array then looping until it reaches that, but I have been looking around W3 schools, Mozilla Dev and here to try and find the most effective way to loop through an array like this. Here is a sample of what I am doing at the moment:

```
var arrayLen = array.length;
var i;
for(i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++) {
    $("#output").append("<li id='item_'" + i + "'>" + array[i].value + "</li>");
}
```

But after reading conflicting responses, I am really not sure what is the best way to do this... Would it be better (performance/effectiveness) to use something like `forEach` or `for` but decline?

Would be great if someone could clear this up for me.

Comment: Do the opposite of whatever w3schools says. (I'm only sort of joking about this.)

Comment: Check this http://colintoh.com/blog/5-array-methods-that-you-should-use-today

Comment: If you are iterating over the whole array, then there will be no difference. Though `forEach` is not supported in IE < 9. You could use `.each()` in jQuery instead though.